# Windows Scheduled Task State/Configuration Change Notifications

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, scheduled-tasks

Looking for methods of exposing notifications for scheduled task state/configuration changes.

Would rather not poll tasks via Service.Schedule or a similar API for performance reasons (poll latency and load to host in question).

For example, a FileSystemWatcher on %SYSTEMROOT%\Tasks or %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\Tasks should raise create/modified/deleted events when a task is created or modified, but task state must be persisted elsewhere. (changes via MMC don't seem to raise events)

Any suggestions as to how I might get performant access to task state information would be greatly appreciated, or pointers on why it's really just not feasible...

Comment: There might be something in the [Task Scheduler 2.0 Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383600(v=vs.85).aspx). C# interface at http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, I had a browse through but couldn't find anything to explicitly register for raised notifications with the terminology I'd expect (event, notification, etc).